Partial Data Migration inside IndexedDB onupgradeneeded
I'm updating objects in an IndexedDB ObjectStore to convert a property from a base64-encoded string to Blobs. However, the operation seems to only succeed partially even though the database's version gets updated. This leaves the object store in an inconsistent state where only some of the entries have been updated to Blobs.
Here's the gist of what I'm doing:
databaseRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
   
  // [Code to get the objectStore, etc. goes here]

  if (event.oldVersion < 2) {  
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(cursorEvent) {
      let cursor = cursorEvent.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
         let value = cursor.value;
         value.data = convertToBlob(value.data); // Note: convertToBlob is synchronous
         cursor.update(value);
         cursor.continue();
      }
    }
  }
}

Since I pushed this update, some users' objectStores contain objects that have not been fully converted. Their database version is up-to-date, but many of their older objects have the property still in the base64 format. What's worse, since the version number of the database got updated, the data resides in this inconsistent format with no chance to run the upgrade again.
I'm curious what I might have done wrong. Is my convertToBlob() too expensive to be done inside onupgradeneeded? (Admittedly, the blobs are large, around 5mb each, so it can take a bit to convert.)
Are using cursors inside onupgradeneeded recommended? I wonder if they're asynchronous and therefore the version gets updated even if it fails?
Any help is appreciated!

If convertToBlob is synchronous and converting large base64 strings to Blobs takes a significant amount of time, it could be blocking the event loop and preventing other operations from completing. While onupgradeneeded is synchronous, it's generally recommended to avoid long-running synchronous operations inside it to prevent blocking.

@Neha I suspect that could be a problem (perhaps users are even closing or refreshing the page while the upgrade is happening)? How would you recommend I approach this if it can't be done inside onupgradeneeded? (I can't make convertToBlob asynchronous, since the transaction will close.)

Instead of converting all records in a single synchronous loop inside onupgradeneeded, you can probably implement a batch processing approach where you process a limited number of records at a time. This will prevent blocking the event loop for too long.

@Neha: Since the version number gets set automatically by the API, how would you recommend I do this?  Loop through the object store on load to look for the old data types and add them to a background web worker or something to get converted? I was hoping for something more straightforward…

Version/discriminate every object in storage. Thus you can transform in a deferred fashion when the value is fetched following get value -> check version -> update the value if old -> return value  procedure. Yes, it's ugly and gets even trickier when you have to also update related values from other stores, but such is the IDB way. onupgradeneeded() callbacks are only useful for declaring object stores and indexes, not for running data migrations in a classical database sense.

Makes sense. Clearly my mental model of how this works was a bit off. It still makes me a bit uncomfortable to think that the schema's state is in doubt, but I guess that's always going to be the case on the client-side, so adding versions and checks along the way is a good approach. Thanks!
